# center an image in a css circle

Tags: html, css

[image]

This is an image in a CSS circle. I want the circle to surround the image so the image is supposed to be in the center. How can i do that?

HTML:

```
<div class="circletag" id="nay">
    <img src="/images/no.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.circletag {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #E6E7ED;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
}
div.circletag.img {

}
```

Comment: `align='center'` ... did you try it?

Comment: The second selector is wrong, it sould be `div.circletag img` or better `div.circletag > img`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the image as background image.

```
.circletag {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #E6E7ED;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    background-image: url(no.png);
    background-position:50% 50%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;    
}
```

If you don't want to have the entire outer div to be clickable, this might work:

```
.circletag {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #E6E7ED;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;    
    text-align:center;
}

.circletag img{
    margin-top:7px;
}
```

Comment: And as Honneykeepa said, use just border-radius.

Answer (score 4):

Keeping your `HTML` intact and using below `CSS` class should work.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="circletag" id="nay">
    <img src="/images/no.png">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.circletag {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #E6E7ED;
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
}
div.circletag>img {
   max-height: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: max-height: 100%; and max-width: 100%; works great in both Portrait and landscape-oriented images. thank you

Comment: I think adding `display: flex;` to circletag will make this work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the easiest way to make an image centered within a circle

```
.circletag{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
} 
.circletag img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write this

```
<div class="circletag" id="nay">
    <div style="padding-top: 7px;text-align: center;"><img src="/images/no.png"></div>
</div>
```

and

this is
`div.circletag.img {}`

like this 
`div.circletag img {}`

Comment: div.circletag.img{
padding:2px;
}

like this?

Comment: Like this: `div.circletag img{ padding:2px; }`

Comment: i don't see how that would help

Answer (score 0):

Unable to test it quickly, but I feel you should try something like this:

```
div.circletag {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #E6E7ED;
    /* For now you can actually use
     * plain border-radius
     *
     * -moz-border-radius: 20px;
     * -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
     */
    border-radius: 20px;

    text-align: center;
}

div.circletag img {
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

at the rounded div, give `text-align:center` and add padding-top. and also **note** that if you add padding, ***you must recalculate the height of the div***.

check the demo here http://jsfiddle.net/fwQq4/

last-thing.. you don't need to specify `display:block`. only use display block, if the rounded element is span or anchor.