# Responsive CSS circles that can hold centered content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, geometry

I am searching for a way to create a responsive CSS3 circle that can hold centered content.
Regarding the circle, I found some good info in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945891/responsive-css-circles). Too bad it seems that one can't center the content in this one.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473443/center-an-image-in-a-css-circle) is also pretty similar to mine, despite the fact it's an image that should be centered. Using a background image in not an option in my case, so this option isn't working for me as well.

Do you have any ideas how I could approach this?
Of course I could use an image, but CSS would be much more elegant!

Comment: Have you considered using SVG?  In what way do you want the circles to be responsive - to the browser window or the content?

Comment: Is the height of the content fixed?

Comment: I just tried SVG - works like a charm, although I still search for a CSS only solution. Yes, the height of the content is fixed.

Comment: @Sven: I had posted an answer which did not have responsive circles, which I then noticed was a requirement of yours, so I deleted it. I have now posted an updated answer that has the responsiveness I believe you desire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Pure CSS requiring many extra wrappers

UPDATED: Original posting (which I deleted) missed the fact that you were seeking a responsive design. [Building upon my answer for the responsive circles question you reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945891/responsive-css-circles/13018712#13018712) seems to work in all CSS3 browsers, [**see fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WTWrB/58/).

**HTML** (requiring five levels of wrapper, I only show one circle in this html)

```
<div class="circles">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <!-- BEG Content -->
            All types of content (see fiddle)
            <!-- END Content -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ditto the above 3 more times -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.circles{
    margin:0px auto;
}
.circles > div {
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    position: relative;
    border-radius:50%;
    -moz-border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
    background:#eee;
}

.circles > div > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.circles > div > div > div {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.circles > div > div > div > div {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

@media (max-width: 320px)
{
    .circles > div {padding: 50%;}
}

@media (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 800px)
{
    .circles > div {padding: 25%;}
}

@media (min-width: 801px)
{
    .circles{width:800px}
    .circles > div {padding: 12.5%;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the height of the content is fixed and you want a CSS method, use the following properties to apply to what's inside the cicle

```
margin: auto; /*will center the element*/
position: relative;
top: 50%;
margin-top: - [here insert the height of the element if you know in advance / 2]px
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not work for me, since I wanted to rotate the circle. 
This does:

HTML

```
<div class="mycircle">
  <div class="mycontent">
    <span>TEXT</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.mycircle {
  width: 30%; 
  height: 0;
  padding: 15% 0; //padding top & bottom must equal width 
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
  background: #dedede; 
}
.mycontent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.mycontent:before {
  content: '';
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.mycontent span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```